# How to disable a button until some text field are filled?

Tags: java, javafx

Using Java FX 8, I have two text fields and a button to validate. I want this button to be disabled until both fields have a valid value.

What is the best way to do this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Add your code please.

Comment: Check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040531/how-to-disable-button-when-textfield-is-empty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/package-summary.html).

Given

```
TextField textField1  ;
TextField textField2  ;
```

You can do

```
BooleanBinding textField1Valid = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
    // check textField1.getText() and return true/false as appropriate
}, textField1.textProperty());

BooleanBinding textField2Valid = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
    // check textField2.getText() and return true/false as appropriate
}, textField2.textProperty());
```

and then

```
Button button = new Button("OK");
button.disableProperty().bind(textField1Valid.not().or(textField2Valid.not()));
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few answers to this question. Ill just post the simple answer.Just add a boolean, and an if-else statement inside the button action listener. If the condition is met, run your button. else do nothing. You could also set up the background colors depending on if this condition is met. To better visualize the button is disabled.

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if(true){ // your boolean operator 
           System.out.println("do something"); // Your button statement 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Simplest answer, but does not match the question, which was to disable the button until both text fields were valid. @James_D answer is more accurate ! Thanks anyway :)