# Disable Button when TableView is empty

Tags: java, button, javafx, tableview, bind

noob need help again. :)

I have a TableView named tblTabela and a Button named btnIzracunaj. What I need is to bind Button disable property with TableView so when TableView has no content Button is disabled.

I did similar binding with another Button when TextFields are empty like this: [How to disable Button when TextField is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040531/how-to-disable-button-when-textfield-is-empty)

```
    BooleanBinding bb = new BooleanBinding() {
{
    super.bind(txtPovrsina.textProperty(),
            txtPrvi.textProperty(),
            txtDrugi.textProperty());
}

@Override
protected boolean computeValue() {
    return (txtPovrsina.getText().isEmpty()
            || txtPrvi.getText().isEmpty()
            || txtDrugi.getText().isEmpty());
}

};
btnDodaj.disableProperty().bind(bb);
```

But my problem is with TableView, I don't know how to set property for binding. What property of TableView should be used? 
I tried this, it doesn't return error, but not working as intended either. I am sure instead of getItems() there should be something else but can't figure out what. :(

```
    BooleanBinding ee = new BooleanBinding() {
{
    super.bind(tblTabela.getItems());
}

@Override
protected boolean computeValue() {
    return (tblTabela.getItems().isEmpty());
}

};
btnIzracunaj.disableProperty().bind(ee);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind the button's disabled property to the observable list like this:

```
button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.size(list).isEqualTo(0));
```

Example code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        HBox root = new HBox();

        // add button
        Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnAction(e -> {

            list.add("Text");

            System.out.println("Size: " + list.size());

        });

        // remove button
        Button removeButton = new Button("Remove");
        removeButton.setOnAction(e -> {

            if (list.size() > 0) {
                list.remove(0);
            }

            System.out.println("Size: " + list.size());

        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(addButton, removeButton);

        // bind to remove button
        removeButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.size(list).isEqualTo(0));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(list));
```