# (fxml) Activate Button when user starts typing on TextField

Tags: java, button, textfield, fxml

I have a TextField in my FXML and a Button to "save" whatever is in the TextField. I'd like to have the Button disabled up until the user starts typing in the TextField, in which the Button becomes clickable , and have it disabled again if the TextField becomes empty again, for me to ensure that you cannot "save" an empty string. I assume an EventHandler would work with this? or not, i don't know. Thank you!

FXML.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="182.0" prefWidth="346.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TextField layoutX="56.0" layoutY="83.0" />
      <Button layoutX="241.0" layoutY="83.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Button when TextField is empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040531/how-to-disable-button-when-textfield-is-empty)

Comment: See linked. Your case is actually simpler, since you only have one `TextField`, but James_D's answer should work just fine.

Comment: @sillyfly cool, worked perfectly! thank you very much