# Returning a node from a cell on GridPane. (JavaFX)

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, gridpane

I have a school project or something like that and I am trying to make a sign up panel for users. This panel opens when user clicks on sign up. It looks like this.

[image: Sign Up Dialog]

What I am trying to do is I want to disable that Create Button and It will be enabled only if there are 3 checks on the dialog.

I am using a GridPane on Dialog and I was thinking about returning those certain nodes (Checks which are ImageViews) at those cells and check whether the condition is true. However, I could not figure out how to return a node from GridPane. If you have any other approach for this problem it is fine too.

This is the code's relevant part.

```
public void SignUp(){

    //Create the custom dialog.
    Dialog signUpDialog = new Dialog();
    //Dialog Title
    signUpDialog.setTitle("Sign Up");

    //Setting "OK" button type.
    ButtonType buttonTypeCreate = new ButtonType("Create", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE);
    //Adding Button types.
    signUpDialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(buttonTypeCreate, ButtonType.CANCEL);

    //Creating the GridPane.
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setHgap(10);
    gridPane.setVgap(10);
    gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

    //Setting the Check Icon.
    Image imageCheck = new Image("resources/check_icon.png");
    //Setting 3 different ImageViews for Check Icon because can't add duplicates to GridPane.
    ImageView imageViewCheck1 = new ImageView(imageCheck);
    ImageView imageViewCheck2 = new ImageView(imageCheck);
    ImageView imageViewCheck3 = new ImageView(imageCheck);

    //Setting the X Icon.
    Image imageX = new Image("resources/x_icon.png");
    //Setting 3 different ImageViews for X Icon because can't add duplicates to GridPane.
    ImageView imageViewX1 = new ImageView(imageX);
    ImageView imageViewX2 = new ImageView(imageX);
    ImageView imageViewX3 = new ImageView(imageX);

    //TextField for User ID.
    TextField textFieldDialogUserID = new TextField();
    textFieldDialogUserID.setPromptText("User ID");
    textFieldDialogUserID.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

    //PasswordField for Password.
    PasswordField passwordFieldDialogPassword = new PasswordField();
    passwordFieldDialogPassword.setPromptText("Password");
    passwordFieldDialogPassword.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

    //PasswordField for Confirm Password.
    PasswordField passwordFieldDialogConfirmPassword = new PasswordField();
    passwordFieldDialogConfirmPassword.setPromptText("Confirm Password");
    passwordFieldDialogConfirmPassword.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

    gridPane.add(new Label("User ID"), 0, 0);
    gridPane.add(textFieldDialogUserID, 1, 0);

    gridPane.add(new Label("Password"), 0, 1);
    gridPane.add(passwordFieldDialogPassword, 1, 1);

    gridPane.add(new Label("Confirm Password"), 0, 2);
    gridPane.add(passwordFieldDialogConfirmPassword, 1, 2);

    gridPane.add(imageViewX1,2,0);
    gridPane.add(imageViewX2,2,1);
    gridPane.add(imageViewX3,2,2);


    signUpDialog.getDialogPane().setContent(gridPane);

    Stage signUpStage = (Stage) signUpDialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
    signUpStage.getIcons().add(new Image("resources/application_icon.png"));

    Optional<Pair<String, String>> result = signUpDialog.showAndWait();


}
```

Comment: Use the bindings approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040531/how-to-disable-button-when-textfield-is-empty

Comment: You can use bindings or you can create a boolean method that checks if User ID's `TextField` has a min length. This boolean method should also check if the two password `TextField`s have a min length and are equal. Then inside of your three `TextField`s' `onkeyReleased` you can do something like: `yourButton.disableProperty().set(yourBooleanCheckMethod());` Your button should be set to disabled from the start.

Comment: Yes, I did it with 3 booleans like locks for each TextField and they will be true when the condition is met. It works fine but still the question remains unanswered tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an appropriate [BooleanBinding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/BooleanBinding.html) which expresses when the button should be *disabled*. You can use the [Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) utility class to create the expression, including comparison, ands and ors. To make the code more readable do a static import of the functions.

Get the create button from your panel and bind the boolean expression to the [disable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#disableProperty) property of your button.

If any of the values change the JavaFX framework will automatically reevaluate the bindings and update the button's state accordingly.

```
import static javafx.beans.binding.Bindings.*;

BooleanBinding notComplete = or(
  equal(textFieldDialogUserID.textProperty(), null),
  equal(passwordFieldDialogPassword.textProperty(), null));

Node createButton = signUpDialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(buttonTypeCreate);
createButton.disableProperty().bind(notComplete);
```

You can use the same mechanism to control the visibility of each checkmark. Create a 'incomplete' `BooleanBinding` for each textfield and bind it with a [`not`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#not-javafx.beans.value.ObservableBooleanValue-) binding to the [`visible`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#visibleProperty) property of the checkmark. Use all these BooleanBindings in a compound `or` to determine the button state. This way the button state and checkmarks will always be in sync.

Comment: I did everything same except I used boolean variable instead of BooleanBinding. What is the difference? Is it worth changing?

Comment: Yes: bindings (and not only boolean bindings) are *the* method in JavaFX to keep your user interface synchronized and consistent with the data model.

Answer (score 1):

> I could not figure out how to return a node from GridPane.

```
    gridPane.getChildren()
```

provides the list of nodes, but you already have your components `textFieldDialogUserID`, `passwordFieldDialogPassword`, `passwordFieldDialogConfirmPassword`.

=> Add an action listener for each of them, that checks the values when its value is changed. depending on the result, enable/disable the Create button (per default, it should be disabled).

you can have an example : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/text-field.htm

Comment: I already have ChangeListener on those 3 fields but didnt post that part because it is too messy. First I did it that way (enable/disable button after the input is changed). The problem with that approach was in some scenarios Create Button can be enabled even though there are no 3 checks. So I have to enable it after 3 checks are present.

Comment: What I'm asking is something like; if(node at row 2==checkImage){enable button}

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Did you use a common validation method that check the value of the 3 fields?

Comment: Yes I did. TextFields and their OnChange methods are working fine. I don't have problems with them. But disabling/enabling create button inside those methods had some problems so I'm trying to enable the button after those methods called by looking at check icons.

Comment: check image is not a good idea (it is a sort of hack, difficult to maintain). Prefer something link binding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040531/how-to-disable-button-when-textfield-is-empty , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040531/how-to-disable-button-when-textfield-is-empty

Comment: But it's not actually checking image. It's like checking the node is at that position in gridpane. But if you say so, i'll try something else.

Comment: Imagine that someone need to change the viewing, let's say having a 4th column with hint (rule for password), could you easily make the change?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I'll do it your way. Thanks. :D