# Alert Message When TextField is empty (javafx)

Tags: javafx

I would like for my code to check if the textfields in my form are empty & then show a pop up alert message. My problem is, even if the textfields are filled in this alert message pops up as soon as I hit "ENTER" anyway. Any help is appreciated !

```
  BtnEnter.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {


        if  (txtfName.getText().isEmpty() | txtlName.getText().isEmpty() | 
                txtMI.getText().isEmpty() | txtStreeAdd.getText().isEmpty()
                | txtCity.getText().isEmpty() | txtZip.getText().isEmpty()
                | txtPhone.getText().isEmpty() | txtEmail.getText().isEmpty()
                | txtSecEmail.getText().isEmpty()) {



            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setTitle("Warning");
            alert.setHeaderText("Required Fields Empty");
            alert.setContentText("The fields highlighted in red must be filled "
                    + "out.\nPlease try again.");
            alert.showAndWait();
```

Comment: What's up with `|`? Maybe `||`?

Comment: I didn't know but `|` appears to be a `bitwise or`.

Comment: You could also take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040531/how-to-disable-button-when-textfield-is-empty) approach or get ideas from it.

Comment: Personally, I don't think `|` and `||` would affect overall outcome. The difference of `|` and `||` is simply that `||` is a short-circuit operator - even when you chain 1000 of them, the whole expression will return `true` as soon it finds the first sub-expression that evaluates to `true`. `|` would simply evaluate all.

Answer (score 3):

I believe part of the issue may be using the single pipe `|` for OR instead of the standard `||`.

However, there's another approach you could take that may be a little easier to read. This is how I handle validation in my applications:

```
public boolean validate() {

        StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();

        // Confirm mandatory fields are filled out
        if (txtfName.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            errors.append("- Please enter a first name.\n");
        }
        if (txtlName.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            errors.append("- Please enter a last name.\n");
        }
        if (txtMI.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            errors.append("- Please enter a middle initial.\n");
        }
        if (txtStreetAdd.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            errors.append("- Please enter a street address.\n");
        }
        if (txtCity.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            errors.append("- Please enter a city.\n");
        }
        if (txtZip.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            errors.append("- Please enter a ZIP code.\n");
        }
        if (txtPhone.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            errors.append("- Please enter a phone number.\n");
        }
        if (txtEmail.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            errors.append("- Please enter a primary email address.\n");
        }
        if (txtSecEmail.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            errors.append("- Please enter a secondary email address.\n");
        }

        // If any missing information is found, show the error messages and return false
        if (errors.length() > 0) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setTitle("Warning");
            alert.setHeaderText("Required Fields Empty");
            alert.setContentText(errors.toString());

            alert.showAndWait();
            return false;
        }

        // No errors
        return true;
    }
```

This has the added benefit of letting the user know exactly what information is missing as well. With this, you simply call the `validate()` method when the user clicks the action button. If `validate()` comes back true, you know you have all the information needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also approach it in this another way without Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING); Here is a piece of code:

```
public boolean validateForm() {

    StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();

    // Confirm mandatory fields are filled out
    if (jTextField1.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
        errors.append("- Please enter a first name.\n");
        jTextField1.requestFocusInWindow();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errors, "Warning!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }
     if (jTextField2.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
        errors.append("- Please enter a last name.\n");
        jTextField2.requestFocusInWindow();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errors, "Warning!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }
     String s = ((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
   if (s.equals("")) {
    errors.append("- Please choose a date.\n");
    jDateChooser1.requestFocusInWindow();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errors, "Warning!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
return false;
```

}

```
   if (jTextField3.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
        errors.append("- Please enter the age.\n");
        jTextField3.requestFocusInWindow();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errors, "Warning!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }




return true;
```

}

In this way, you can check if users know what exactly missing and show them an alert message. Add a listener for the button.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   if(validateForm()) {
      System.out.println("First name: "+jTextField1.getText());
      System.out.println("Last name: "+jTextField2.getText());
      System.out.println("Date: "+jDateChooser1.getDate());
       System.out.println("Age: "+jTextField3.getText());
   }
}
```