# Binding button to multiple properties not working

Tags: java, javafx, binding

My button is disabled but once I fill out my username, password and comboBox I want the button to be enabled. So I used bindings for this but when I use it with my comboBox I get a bindings cannot be applied to given types error. Is there another way to do this as I want to add dates and spinners in the future.

```
button.disableProperty().bind(
       Bindings.or(
             username.textProperty().isEmpty(),
             password.textProperty().isEmpty(),
             comboBox.valueProperty().isNull()
       )
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Button when TextField is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040531/how-to-disable-button-when-textfield-is-empty)

Comment: Look at @James_D answer in the duplicate.

Comment: This part may be slightly different `comboBox.valueProperty().isNull()`. Not sure.

Comment: @Sedrick It is not the same as it includes valueProperty and not textProperty as shown in James_D's answer.

Comment: I figured it was not exactly the same. The idea is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Bindings.or` only takes 2 parameters, not 3. You need to apply `or` twice:

```
button.disableProperty().bind(
         username.textProperty().isEmpty().or(
             password.textProperty().isEmpty().or(
                 comboBox.valueProperty().isNull()))
);
```

Alternatively you could use `createBooleanBinding` which also would allow for readable more complex expressions:

```
button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
    () -> username.getText().isEmpty() || password.getText().isEmpty() || (comboBox.getValue() == null),
    username.textProperty(), password.textProperty(), comboBox.valueProperty()
));
```

Comment: Thank you Fabian.