# How to disable button if the TextField empty?

Tags: if-statement, javafx, text, textfield

I can't disable my button. In the below code, **`accept`** is a `Button` and **`email`** is a `TextField`.

```
email.setOnAction(ae -> {
    if(!email.getText().isEmpty()) {
        accept.setDisable(false);
    } else
        accept.setDisable(true);
});
```

It doesn't do anything if I write in the text field.

Comment: `onAction` only triggers, when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed. Is the desired behavour potentially updating the state of the button on every change of the `TextField` text? BTW: the `if` statement could be easily replaced with `accept.setDisable(email.getText().isEmpty());`

Comment: Better one https://stackoverflow.com/a/23041348/269514

Answer (score 6):

Following Zephyr's answer, you can directly bind it inside your button:

```
button1.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(textField1.textProperty()));
```

Or if you want to disable a button when multiple text fields are empty:

```
button1.disableProperty().bind(
    Bindings.isEmpty(textField1.textProperty())
        .or(Bindings.isEmpty(textField2.textProperty()))
        .or(Bindings.isEmpty(textField3.textProperty()))
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple `BooleanBinding` bound to the `Button`'s `disabledProperty`. It takes only 2 lines of code to accomplish this:

```
BooleanBinding isTextFieldEmpty = Bindings.isEmpty(textField.textProperty());
button.disableProperty().bind(isTextFieldEmpty);
```

You can use the MCVE below to see it in action:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BooleanBindingExample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // TextField and Button
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        root.getChildren().addAll(textField, button);

        // Create a BooleanBinding for the textField to hold whether it is null
        BooleanBinding isTextFieldEmpty = Bindings.isEmpty(textField.textProperty());

        // Now, bind the Button's disableProperty to that BooleanBinding
        button.disableProperty().bind(isTextFieldEmpty);

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following **miKel**'s answer, you can define the button's `disable` property without importing the `Bindings` class:

```
button1.disableProperty().bind(
    textField1.textProperty().isEmpty() 
    .or(textField2.textProperty().isEmpty())
    .or(textField3.textProperty().isEmpty())
);
```