# In my javafx application i have some scenes with textfields and button can i set the button on disabled when it s empty and enabled when it s not?

Tags: java, javafx, action

In my javafx application i have some scenes with textfields and button can i set the button on disabled when it s empty and enabled when it s not ? like a test on fields when im typing i have to change the value of the proprety of the value ! and when i changed when it s empty i can t enable it after i typed some thing[image] `if (tv_np.getText().length()<1) {btn_c.setDisable(true); }else btn_c.setDisable(false);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable button if the TextField empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54728265/how-to-disable-button-if-the-textfield-empty)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the textproperty of the textfield and bind the disabled property of the button to it:

```
btn_c.disableProperty().bind(tv_np.textProperty().isEmpty());
```